# Double anchoring regular expressions

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, anchor

I want to accept an arbitrary regular expression from the user and anchor it on both sides in order to enforce a full match (`^<user's-regex>$`) however I don't know if I have to take into account the fact that the user may have already anchored his regex.

It looks like Perl, C++, .NET and JavaScript all allow <del>double</del> multiple anchoring.

```
"hello" =~ /^h/ # true
"hello" =~ /^^h/ # true
"hello" =~ /^^^h/ # true
"hello" =~ /e/ # true
"hello" =~ /^e/ # false
"hello" =~ /^^e/ # false
```

Does anyone know if this is specified to work this way? Can I depend on this behaviour or is it an accident that is liable to change in the future?

---

**Edit:** The reason we need this is that we're using VBScript's regex's (from COM), we're using `match` however this returns all matches so it's much slower to match the string `abc` to `.*a.*` than to `^.*a.*$`. By using the anchoring as suggested by [@Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker) we speed matches up (for long strings) by more than a factor of 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can depend on this behavior. The regex engine doesn't mind asserting the same thing once, twice, or a hundred times in a row.

However, instead of simply adding anchors around the regex, you should also add a non-capturing group around it:

`^(?:` - user regex - `)$` or preferably, if your regex flavor allows this: `\A(?:` - user regex - `)\Z`

Otherwise, you'll trip up if the user uses alternation in his regex. Compare:

```
user regex:         hello|bye
anchored regex:     ^hello|bye$      // alternation now affects anchors
correctly anchored: ^(?:hello|bye)$
```

Comment: I'm updating the question with the motivation, thanks your answer was very helpful.